# Query com Join muito lento

Tags: sql

Olá,

alguém poderia me dizer porque essa Query está tão lenta? Eu estou limitando a pesquisa a 10 resultados por vez, para paginação, porém ela está demorando mais de 10 segundos pra completar.

```
select 
    `orders`.`id`, 
    `orders`.`i_food_merchant_id`, 
    `orders`.`preparation_start_date_time`, 
    `orders`.`display_id`, 
    `orders`.`status`, 
    `orders`.`customer`, 
    `orders`.`created_at`, 
    `deliveries`.`dispached_at`, 
    `deliveries`.`delivery_man_id`, 
    `delivery_men`.`name` as `delivery_man_name` 
    
from 
    `orders` 
    
inner join 
        `deliveries` 
    on 
        `orders`.`id` = `deliveries`.`order_id`
        
inner join 
        `delivery_men` 
    on 
        `deliveries`.`delivery_man_id` = `deliveries`.`delivery_man_id` 
        
order by 
    `orders`.`preparation_start_date_time` desc 
    
limit 10;
```

[Resultado da query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdWRm.png)

Comment: Sem conhecer a engine de Banco de Dados, o esquema das tabelas envolvidas nas consultas, sem saber se há ou não particionamento, sem conhecer os índices ativos, sem saber a quantidade de registros e sem conhecer o plano de execução da consulta fica difícil fazer uma análise.

Answer (score -3):

Uma coisa que identifiquei olhando sua query é que seu segundo INNER JOIN está comparando duas informações iguais, está faltando você informar o ID dá tabela "delivery_men".

Inner join incorreto:
INNER JOIN `delivery_men` ON `deliveries`.`delivery_man_id` = `deliveries`.`delivery_man_id`

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).